# Select more with the distance n vertices in edit mode

Tags: vertices, select

The usual select more will add the nearest vertices to selection.Is there a way that I can add the distance n points in loop directions to selection ? (the nearest is distance 1,distance 2 means skip one vertice) Also can we do this via a short cut like ctrl + ?
There are two situations.

We start from this [image]

First one:[image]

[image]

Second one  :  [image]
[image]

Comment: What does "n" in this context mean, is it abbreviation for number of points? Screenshot of result before "operation" and after would be more than useful. You can [edit] the question with that

Comment: So what you want to achieve is for a script to detect a pattern and then select more vertices with that pattern? 

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady maybe custom patterns are more difficult to achieve,I just want this rectangle version to create vertex weight to control miro mesh of different size.

Comment: Try the checker deselect option (in the select menu of the 3d window).

Comment: @joshsanfelici using the option,the remaining part are lines with thickness in y=x direction,it doesn't coincident with my description.

Comment: The end result on those screenshots is doable, but not using the first screenshots as a starting point. You can use standard Ctrl+left click to select a line of vertices, run checker deselect (default), then selecting another line, checker deselect, etc.Or you can select a vertex, then another next to it, then Ctrl+Shift+Numpad plus, then you get selection pattern line by line.